# Adding fields to custom content entity

Tags: entities

I'm creating a new content entity called *Points*. My code already creates the table and its fields, but i cant see the fields in the entity form. I thought that fields in *baseFieldDefinitions*() should to be shown in the form . What i'm doing wrong? it only shows a pair of these fields:

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

    $fields['uid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
    ->setLabel(t('User ID'))
    ->setDescription(t('The user ID of the operation author.'))
    ->setSettings(array(
      'target_type' => 'user',
      'default_value' => 0,
    ))
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);


    $fields['target_type'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text')
    ->setLabel(t('Target Type'))
    ->setDescription(t('Tipo de entidad sobre la que se realiza la operación'))
    ->setDefaultValue(0)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['target_entity'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
    ->setLabel(t('Target Entity'))
    ->setDescription(t('ID de la entidad sobre la que se realiza la operación'))
    ->setDefaultValue(0)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['operacion'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
    ->setLabel(t('Operación Realizada'))
    ->setDescription(t('Operación realizada (create, update, delete)'))
    ->setSettings([
      'allowed_values' => [
        'create' => 'create',
        'update' => 'update',
        'delete' => 'delete',
      ],
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
      'label' => 'visible',
      'type' => 'list_default',
      'weight' => 6,
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'options_select',
      'weight' => 6,
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['timestamp'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
    ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
    ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
    ->setDescription(t('The time that the points was last edited.'))
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['points'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
    ->setLabel(t('Points'))
    ->setDescription(t('Points to grant'))
    ->setDefaultValue(0)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['langcode'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('language')
    ->setLabel(t('Language code'))
    ->setDescription(t('The points language code.'))
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    return $fields;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add new fields to already existing entity you need to write update hook.

Refer https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/Bhanu951-3103712/-/blob/8.x-dev/omdb_api/omdb_api.install#L178 for sample code

Relevant Change Record [#2554097](https://www.drupal.org/node/2078241)